# Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed when trying to sort table

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I've trying to look for an answer on my error in Excel, what I try to do is to filter the contents in a column on a table from largest to smallest. I recorded a Macro doing this but whenever I put this code into a button I get an "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed" after I try to use it.

```
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FDTHC").ListObjects("FilterDTHC").Sort.SortFields. _
    Clear

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FDTHC").ListObjects("FilterDTHC").Sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("Time"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
    :=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FDTHC").ListObjects("FilterDTHC").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

The VBA highlights the following part of the code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FDTHC").ListObjects("FilterDTHC").Sort.SortFields. _
    Add Key:=Range("Time"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
    :=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

I appreciate any help given, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range set in the command is on the ActiveSheet. It should be linked to Sheet("FDTHC").

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FDTHC").ListObjects("FilterDTHC").Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FDTHC").Range("Time"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
    Order:=xlDescending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much that solved the problem, now I have a second problem when I try to run the script it gives me a "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" at this part: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FDTHC").ListObjects("FilterDTHC").Sort.SortFields. _
    Clear`

Comment: The error indicates that one of the objects mentioned in that line of code doesn't exist. Could be the Worksheet, the ListObject or the SortFields. This could be the kind of error which only occurs during testing because all objects normally do exist. If your code must accommodate the possibility that there really is something missing, use `On Error Resume Next` followed by `If Err.Number = 9 Then` and rectify the situation in the code that follows.